# Can't open Electron webview links with target = blank

Tags: webview, window, electron

I'm using Electron I have a webview which display an external website but I can't succeed to show the additional window normally opened by links on this site and which have target = _blank.

```
<a href="mentions.html" target="_blank">Mentions légales </a>
```

I tried with

```
webpreferences="nativeWindowOpen=yes" allowpopups
```

But it didn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging into the documentation I wrote this code (code located in the renderer):

```
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron').remote
```

..........

```
 webview1.addEventListener('new-window', (e) => {
    const protocol = require('url').parse(e.url).protocol
    if (protocol === 'http:' || protocol === 'https:') {
      //shell.openExternal(e.url)
      let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
      win.loadURL(e.url);
    }
  })
```

The line `shell.openExternal(e.url)` open the url of the link in a tab of the default browser.
And by using a new BrowserWindow, the new windows are Electron Window.

Comment: can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206387/target-blank-based-link-in-webview-in-electron-js-are-not-opening-when-nativewi

Answer (score 6):

With a webview, you can actually handle these on the main process quite easily.

Which also allows you to disable nodeIntegration should that be a requirement.

```
// Listen for web contents being created
app.on('web-contents-created', (e, contents) => {

  // Check for a webview
  if (contents.getType() == 'webview') {

    // Listen for any new window events
    contents.on('new-window', (e, url) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      shell.openExternal(url)
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: In case anybody is looking how to attach this event to BrowserView: `browserView.webContents.on('new-window', (e, url) => { /* handle window open */ });`

Comment: can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69206387/target-blank-based-link-in-webview-in-electron-js-are-not-opening-when-nativewi