# target=_blank based link in webview in electron.js are not opening when nativeWindowOpen is true in parent window

Tags: javascript, webview, electron

I have simple [electron.js](https://www.electronjs.org) application, [electron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) in which I am using [`<webview>`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag).

By default links in which `target=_blank` is set does not open inside `webview`.

There is some workaround by listening to [`new-window`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#event-new-window) event given at [Can't open Electron webview links with target = blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914542/cant-open-electron-webview-links-with-target-blank)

But this workaround does not work when `nativeWindowOpen: true` in `webPreferences` in parent window. Rather application get crashed when I am adding `allowpopups` on `MacOS` with error `exited with signal SIGSEGV`

```js
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
      webviewTag: true,
      nativeWindowOpen: true // This flag is not letting recieve new-window event from webview
    }
  })
```

`index.html` is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <webview id="foo" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp" style="display:inline-flex; width:640px; height:480px" allowpopups></webview>

    <h1>click on Try it yuorself button in webview</h1>

    <!-- You can also require other files to run in this process -->
    <!-- <script src="./renderer.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get webview links where `target=_blank` working keeping `nativeWindowOpen: true` in parent window?

`nativeWindowOpen` is going to be set `true` by default according to [Planned Breaking API Changes (15.0)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#default-changed-nativewindowopen-defaults-to-true)

Comment: do you not need to set `nativeWindowOpen` true on the webview tag: `webpreferences="nativeWindowOpen=yes" allowpopups`?

Comment: I tried adding `webpreferences="nativeWindowOpen=yes"` but still did not get call to `new-window` event. Adding `allowpopups` also crash my electron app.

Comment: why does `allowpopups` crash your app? Paste the code that you're using to intercept the new windows? I don't see it

Comment: Further to your request on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914542/ I didn't have time to build a test code but perhaps you can have a llok in the doc  https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open for:
"To customize or cancel the creation of the window, you can optionally set an override handler with webContents.setWindowOpenHandler() from the main process. Returning false cancels the window, while returning an object sets the BrowserWindowConstructorOptions used when creating the window....."

Comment: @pushkin: I havev added code of `index.html` or you can also try setting `nativeWindowOpen: true` like in my code and `allowpopups` like in my `index.html` and try to click on link which have `target=_blank`. On my MacOS its crashing

Answer (score 0):

I've tried and write a gist with Electron fiddle. Perhaps I didn't catch your problem but for me it's working
https://gist.github.com/deb6ed0fa37860fdfc0d51c6782f4152

Comment: I have added my `index.html` code. you can also try setting `nativeWindowOpen: true` like in my code and `allowpopups` like in my `index.html` and try to click on link which have `target=_blank`. On my MacOS its crashing

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/29874 which got fixed.

electron version 12.0.14 or higher is working fine for this problem.